# How to measure the size of used memory in Java-services?

Tags: java, memory, memory-leaks, garbage-collection

Several Java services are running on the tomcat server.
It is necessary to measure the memory consumption of each of the services.
Not the total memory consumption, but in the context of each service,how much memory each service consumes.

What means can be used to measure the used memory of each of the services?
At some point I need to understand who eats up how much memory.

Comment: I would guess that Flight Recorder can fullfill your needs (https://docs.oracle.com/javacomponents/jmc-5-4/jfr-runtime-guide/toc.htm)

Comment: Erik, thank you, i will try that